# Camel route not getting started Issue in spring boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

1. I am using a spring boot application.
2. I have camel component which is configured as follows:

```
@Configuration
class FrameworkPipelineInboundSQSRoute
    @Autowired
    private SalesOrderGetHelper salesOrderGetHelper;
    @Bean(name = "frameworkPipelineInboundSQSRouteBuilder")
    public RouteBuilder route() {
        String inboundSqsUri = SQSUtil.buildSqsUri(
            financialOrderInboundSqsName, maxConsumerThreads, maxMessageBatchSize, 
            deleteIfFiltered, messageAttributeNames, defaultVisibilityTimeout
        );
        log.info("framework pipeline Inbound SQS Uri={}", inboundSqsUri);
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                errorHandler(
                  ...
                    from("direct:xx") route code goes here..
```

When i Start application using bootRun command,
I get message such as:

```
INFO 2022-03-09 15:17:44,842 [main] traceID= app=frameworkpipeline ver=unspecified.0 cl=org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanP
ostProcessorChecker : Bean org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration of type org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration is not eligible for 
getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

and sometimes, camel route not started like here:
INFO 2022-03-09 06:48:49,852 [main] traceID= app=frameworkpipeline ver=unspecified.12 cl=org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext : Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started
```

I saw thread which said to add
`@Lazy` instead of `@Autowired`, I tried that as well. Getting same issue.
Can you tell how to resolve this issue as SQS messages are not consumed as no camel route has started.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Does anything in your application refer to frameworkPipelineInboundSQSRouteBuilder? If not, there won't be any reason to create it.